# Error when trying to keep code inside of Main method

Tags: c#, c#-5.0

I am trying to teach myself this so I am sure this is obvious.

I am trying to create 2 classes that I can call instances of in Program/Main. One class is a string to double tryparse method and the other will just hold variables that will be used for many things.

My problem is I can only set Main up without error  if the Main Method is only holding my new instance of class statements so I am exiting code immediately.

I will post the code to the Main. Newbie code and question, any help is much appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SetupMath
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) 

        //Bringing in  classes to inherit methods from
        {
            StringToDouble IntakeParse = new StringToDouble();
            SetUpVar GuitAction = new SetUpVar();
        }

        // new instance of the StringToDouble class
        // getting variable value "action" from string to double tryparse 

        public class StringToDouble 
        {
            public string action { get; set; }

            //converting "action" variable to "what"
            public string What
            {
                 get { return this.action; }
                 set { this.action = value; }
            }
        }

        public class SetUpVar // new instance of the SetVar class 
        {       
            public string GuitAction { get; set; }         
            public string What { get; set; }

            //Do something code
            public void Work() 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number", GuitAction);
                What = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("You entered:  " + What);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mike, it is very unclear what you are trying to achieve, and there are numerous (conceptual) problems with your code. Some advice for the future, or for improving this question by doing an [edit]: (1) Try to explain what the code is supposed to do (i.e. what you want to achieve with it), (2) what is not working the way you expected it would.

Comment: Mike, you are doing an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead, you should describe **what** it is that you want to achieve, i.e. what the perceived problem is that is to be solved, **before** describing how you envision your code is going to solve this, and what your problems with it are.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing **StringToDouble** and **SetUpVar** classes inside the **Program** class scope that's why they are visible only there. If you want your classes to be visible inside the whole namespace you should write them outside of Program class

Comment: Then I need to be bringing in the instances of methods some other way. Thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In a nutshell. I plan on writing many programs to create conversational gcode for my lathe. What is the best way to use a string to double tryparse. I thought I could create a method in a separate class and inherit its parsing on user input. Sorry, at this point in my newness to OOP it is hard to put into words.